# nodejs how can i use multidimensional array and push values in it?

Tags: arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

i am trying to create a new `multidimensional array` from the data i am getting from 3rd part API.

```
"output":[
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"adam",
     "tokens":29
  },
  {
     "is_indb":true,
     "name":"aaron",
     "tokens":2,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"adam",
     "tokens":3,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"axel",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"andy",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"bob",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"aldo",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"julia",
     "tokens":5,
  }
]
```

i would like to create a new `array` and fill it with data from response.
but i would like to do some pre checks like

take only those whose, `is_indb = false`
take only those whose, name starts with `a`

so the final array will be, all those whosse `is_indb = true` and name starts with `a`

```
var newaray = [[adam,29],[adam,3],[axel,5],[andy,5],[aldo,5]];
```

---

so far i have tried using `_pluck` and getting some weird outputs. i am able to get sible elements using `_pluck` but cant get multiple items.

i can think of logic like this

```
var newaray = [];

if( (_pluck(msg.output,'is_indb') == false  && ((_pluck(msg.output,'name').substring(0, 1) == "a")){
    newaray.push( [ _.pluck(msg.output, 'name') , _.pluck(msg.output, 'token')] );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` and `map`:

```
var filteredOutput = output
    .filter(function(elem) {
        // The return statement should return true,
        // if you want the element to pass into the new array.
        return elem.is_indb === false && typeof elem.name === "string" && elem.name.indexOf('a') === 0;
    })
    .map(function(elem) {
        return [elem.name, elem.tokens];
    });
```

or with ES6:

```
let filteredOutput = output
    .filter(elem => elem.is_indb === false && typeof elem.name === "string" && elem.name.indexOf('a') === 0)
    .map(elem => [elem.name, elem.tokens])
```

with ES6 and using regex (inspired by `Peter Grainger`'s answer, but also case insensitive):

```
let filteredOutput = output
        .filter(elem => elem.is_indb === false && /^a/i.test(elem.name))
        .map(elem => [elem.name, elem.tokens])
```

and by the way, what you posted is an array of objects, not a multidimensional array, which is an array of arrays.

Comment: when i do console.log(filteredOutput ), i am getting empty arrays. [] [] []

Comment: What does your `output` variable look like?

Comment: msg = JSON.parse(packet.utf8Data).x  and then using msg.output

Comment: so then, did you filter `msg.output`?
the code is working for me - I'm getting only `aaron`, which is the only object meeting your criteria.

Comment: @AMB I've edited the code to account for your edit, which asks for the filter to pick elements where `is_indb === false` instead of `true`.

Comment: yes, this is working, but sometimes api gives null so i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null

Comment: return element.is_indb === false && element.name.indexOf('a') === 0;  at name

Comment: added a prettier regex version which also accounts for null. be careful, however, because if for some reason you'd want to test for `n` instead of `a`, `null` will be a valid name. same goes for `u` and `undefined`.

Comment: oops, fixed it.

Comment: if i use your first code then i am getting all [] [] []

Comment: and shouldn't typeof elem === "string" be typeof element === "string"

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filter then a map?

```js
const output = [
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"adam",
     "tokens":29
  },
  {
     "is_indb":true,
     "name":"aaron",
     "tokens":2,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"adam",
     "tokens":3,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"axel",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"andy",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"bob",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"aldo",
     "tokens":5,
  },
  {
     "is_indb":false,
     "name":"julia",
     "tokens":5,
  }
]

const transform = output.filter(value => /^a/.test(value.name) && !value.is_indb)
                        .map(value => [value.name, value.tokens])
                        
console.log(transform)
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question as it does not filter by `is_indb`.

Comment: its by far the simplest code. but there are some empty [] are showing in output, i guess some objects dont even have a single object which satisfies our condition.

Comment: it IS simpler, however it is also potentially error-prone in case you decide to change things later, (`/^n/.test(null) === true`).

Comment: @AMB That is probably because name and/or value are not set you could add that to the filter.  nadavvadan, agree, solve a problem with regex, now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.filter and get the output in this form

```
op = [{ obj1 } ,{obj2}];
```

but as you want to remove some keys also then you can use _.pick

```
var op = _.filter(ip , function(obj){
    if(obj.is_indb == false && obj.name[0] == 'a'){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
})
//so now you have all the entries filtered out
var opAltered = _.pick(op,['name','tokens']);

//you will get this result

/*
    opAltered = [
        {
            name : <something>,
            tokens : <something>
        },{
            ...
        }
    ]
*/
```

or If you want array you can use this

```
opAltered = _.map(op,['name','tokens'];
```

I have used more code to make you understand properly you can reduce it once you understand Thanks.

Comment: if (nativeMap && obj.map === nativeMap) return obj.map(iterator, context); TypeError: [object Array] is not a function

Comment: I have used lodash for it var _ = require('lodash')